# Получить значение url из браузера

Tags: c#

После открытия браузера при помощи

```
Process proc = Process.Start("explorer.exe", "http://www.google.com");
```

и после логина пользователя в аккаунт, нужно из браузера получить url с токеном.
Реально это сделать и как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться selenium:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //Здесь может быть любой другой браузер, не только "лиса"
string url =  driver.Url;
```

Либо, если не хотите ничего лишнего устанавливать в проект, используйте стандартный webbrowser, только придется кинуть его на форму:

```
 string url = webBrowser1.Document.Url.OriginalString;
```

Comment: А зачем webBrowser, если есть легковесный веб-клиент?

Comment: @iluxa1810 тоже верно, чет совсем о нем забыл)